# What is best practice for adding additional controller to Magento Core Modules

Tags: magento, controller

I want to add additional controller named SkuController to CatalogSearch Core module. 
What is best practice to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you do, do not modify the core, but create a custom module, and ensure you always call the parent functions where possible.

Use ModuleCreater to simplify this task:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/modulecreator.html

Have a look at Ivan's video tutorial, just ignore the php unit testing bit, but he explains the whole lot, especially half way during the video.

http://vimeo.com/35937480

Also look at this sample for some more ideas:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-3-magento-controller-dispatch

Good best practice ideas shared on both links.

A controller class could look like this:

```
class Mycompany_myMod_Adminhtml_myModController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_action
{

    protected function _initAction() {
        $this->loadLayout()
            ->_setActiveMenu('custompromos/items')
            ->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Items Manager'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item Manager'));

        return $this;
    }   

    public function indexAction() {
        $this->_initAction()
            ->renderLayout();
    }

    public function editAction() {
        $id     = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        //Some code here
    }

    public function newAction() {
        $this->_forward('edit');
    }

    public function saveAction() {
        if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {
               //Some code here             
        }

    }

    public function deleteAction() {
        if( $this->getRequest()->getParam('id') > 0 ) {
            try {
                //Some code here
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
            }
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }

    public function massDeleteAction() {
        //Some code here
        $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
    }

    public function massStatusAction()
    {
        //Some code here
        $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
    }

    public function exportCsvAction()
    {
        $fileName   = 'somedata.csv';
        $content    = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('mymodule/adminhtml_mymodule_grid')
            ->getCsv();

        $this->_sendUploadResponse($fileName, $content);
    }

    public function exportXmlAction()
    {
        $fileName   = 'somedata.xml';
        $content    = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('mymodule/adminhtml_mymodule_grid')
            ->getXml();

        $this->_sendUploadResponse($fileName, $content);
    }

    protected function _sendUploadResponse($fileName, $content, $contentType='application/octet-stream')
    {
        $response = $this->getResponse();
        $response->setHeader('HTTP/1.1 200 OK','');
        $response->setHeader('Pragma', 'public', true);
        $response->setHeader('Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0', true);
        $response->setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename='.$fileName);
        $response->setHeader('Last-Modified', date('r'));
        $response->setHeader('Accept-Ranges', 'bytes');
        $response->setHeader('Content-Length', strlen($content));
        $response->setHeader('Content-type', $contentType);
        $response->setBody($content);
        $response->sendResponse();
        die;
    }
}
```

Comment: Added some more info for you.

Answer (score 1):

all extra funcionality should made by module. I recomend made a new module with the new controller.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Actually, solution for my problem is to create module that will share same route as CatalogSearch Core module.